# "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)" - Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, terminal, visual-studio-code

I have problems with opening VS code Intergrated Terminal while debugging a python file. 
VS code says: '$ {file} can not be resolved. Please open an editor.'

I was working with: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNFgRUD2w68

My launch.json

````
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopOnEntry": false
        }```
    ]
}
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you have a workspace folder open?

Comment: I have opened only launch.json and settings.json... Do I have to open a workspace folder?

Comment: And this is only a part of this launch.json, but I have problems only with this Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio Code you need to open a workspace folder before running and debugging Python scripts. If not, VSCode isn't able to resolve for example `${file}` or `${workspaceFolder}`.

Once you have opened a workspace folder, the color of the status bar at the bottom changes (depending on what theme you have selected), indicating that you're now inside a workspace. Then just click on the debug symbol on the left side bar and on the gear symbol in the upper left (where you can click on to start debugging).

This will automatically create a **.vscode** folder inside the root directory (your workspace) and add a **launch.json** within it. Now `${file}` can be resolved.

Here is a list of [predefined variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables) supported by VScode which are very useful for configuring debug options.